# How to extract lines with a specific column using awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file which have rows like this:

```
004662484   4   0   0   0   0
```

The second column is number 4, and I want to use this number to extract this line into 4 lines like this:

```
004662484   0   0   0   0   0
004662484   1   0   0   0   0
004662484   2   0   0   0   0
004662484   3   0   0   0   0
```

How to do that using either `awk` or `sed` or both? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 {  reps = $2;  for (i = 0; i < reps; i++) { $2 = i; print $0; } }
```

Comment: Nice solution.  PS you do not need the last `;` after `print $0`